# Given an EC2 instance with an EBS AMI, How can I update the AMI's snapshot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

on EC2 my app servers are running the same EBS AMI. How can I update this AMI's snapshot to contain the latest configuration settings and site code?

I can only find tutorials that talk about creating new EBS AMIs, none that talk about updating running AMIs.

Comment: This is probably a better question for serverfault

Answer (score 6):

I believe your only option is to create a new AMI from one of your configured instances. Then you will have to spin up new instances based on that AMI and remove the ones on the old AMI.

Comment: Do you know of a tutorial on how to do this from the web console? These are EBS AMIs, do I clone the AMI? etc? thx

Answer (score 0):

An AMI image is an image of an EC2 instance at a given point in time, like a photograph.  When you launch an EC2 instance from an AMI, the AMI is not considered running.  The AMI is copied to your EC2 instance and your EC2 instance is running.  The original AMI image is not affected (and cannot be affected) by any changes done to your EC2 instance.

If you make changes to your EC2 instance and you want to preserve them in an AMI, you must create a new AMI image.  When you do this, you can delete the old AMI image if you don't need it anymore, or keep it around if you are going to want to launch new EC2 instances from before you made your configuration changes.